# R - Merge and Replace Column If ID Found on Another Data Frame

Tags: r, if-statement, merge

I have two data frames as below and am trying to improve my code so the `letters` column in `df1` should replaced with the `letters` column in `df2` if they match.

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,3,2,4,5), Letters = LETTERS[1:5], stringsAsFactors = F)
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,3,4), Letters2 = "F", stringsAsFactors = F)

desired:
ID  letters
1   F
2   B
3   F
4   D
5   F
```

It would be like doing the following by in one line:

```
desired <- merge(df1, df2, by = "ID", all.x = T)
desired$letters <- ifelse(is.na(desired$letters2), desired$letters, desired$letters2)
desired$letters2 <- NULL
```

Comment: Your desired output is not reflecting the input data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1%>%
   left_join(df2)%>%
   mutate(Letters=coalesce(letters2,Letters),letters2=NULL)
Joining, by = "ID"
  ID Letters
1  1       F
2  2       B
3  3       F
4  4       F
5  5       E
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use the numeric 'ID' as index to change the values in 'Letters' to those of 'letters2' (which are all 'F's)

```
df1$Letters[df2$ID] <- df2$letters2
df1
#  ID Letters
#1  1       F
#2  2       B
#3  3       F
#4  4       F
#5  5       E
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, Letters := Letters2, on = .(ID)]
df1
#   ID Letters
#1:  1       F
#2:  3       F
#3:  2       C
#4:  4       F
#5:  5       E
```

Comment: i have edited my post because what if the id's are out of order. also, for some reason when i try to apply this to my actual situation, i get the following error: `replacement has 63150 rows, data has 1968`

Comment: @alexb523 It is based on the example you provided earlier.  I assumed it is the pattern